# open PMD issues in windows 10

Tags: python, anaconda

I am trying to open openPMD_notebook

I have installed anaconda distribution then installed all other things necessary and set up the path variables.

Everything is working good except opemPMD_notebook

It always says 'openPMD_notebook' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

```
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDmm6.png)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OG2LM.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tHwd.png)

Please Help

I have uninstalling and reinstalling everythig 2-3 times but the problem still remains same. However everything is working fine on other computers

I am actually trying this to work

https://fbpic.github.io/how_to_run.html